# fatal error: 'AppDelegate.h' file not found #import "AppDelegate.h"

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

### Description

My project was previously working but ever since I added some babel plugins it fails to compile. **Note that I do not know if they are correlated, even when I remove what I added, it still throws the same error.**

**My .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-async-generator-functions",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-regenerator"
  ]
}
```

### Error:

The following errors are very vague.

> /Users/XXXXXX/WebstormProjects/FluxRN/ios/FluxRN/main.m:12:9:
>   fatal error: 'AppDelegate.h' file not found
>
> ## import "AppDelegate.h"
>
> ```
>     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated.
> ```
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  CompileC
>   build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/FluxRN.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FluxRN.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
>   FluxRN/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (1 failure)

Even if the build fails, emulator starts and this error appears.

[image]

### Question

What is causing the build to crash?

*I find it confusing that the AppDelegate.h can not be found. When I open my iOS project in XCode, it's clearly in the root directory of the project.*

**Note: Going back to what I had previously still throws the same error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-native upgrade` seemed to have solved the issue regarding:

> fatal error: 'AppDelegate.h' file not found #import “AppDelegate.h”

After react-native update the folder structure in the generated iOS was not uptodate. Running the above command will fix the issue. However, I'm still getting the exception (from the screen shot), thus this probably comes from another issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
-#import "AppDelegate.h"
+#import "../../../ios/ReactNativeExampleProject/AppDelegate.h"
```

Anyone looking for another solution, giving a specific path for imports worked for me